# TestContainers Scala Cassandra Random Ports

Tags: scala, testcontainers

I am running tests in scala using spark and cassandra, for the test I am using testcontainers and for some work reasons we are not using the scala variant of testcontainers, the problem with testcontainers the ports are randomly assigned and I don't know what parameter to use to get the port so I can conect

```
//code block
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ConnectorSpec extends AnyFlatSpec
  with BeforeAndAfterAll{
  val container =  new CassandraContainer("cassandra:latest")
  container.withExposedPorts(9042)
  container.waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort())
  container.start()

  val ip = container.getContainerIpAddress() //output localhost
  val port = container.getMappedPort(9042)
  val cluster = container.getCluster()
  val session = cluster.connect()


  session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS test WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':'1'};")
  session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.eureka (id int PRIMARY KEY,  city varchar, role varchar);")

  session.execute("INSERT INTO test.tester (id,  city, role) VALUES (1, 'Jakarta', 'Devops')")
  session.execute("SELECT * FROM test.tester")

  assert(container.isRunning)

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("ReadCassandra")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
  spark.setCassandraConf(CassandraConnectorConf.KeepAliveMillisParam.option(10000))
  spark.setCassandraConf(cluster.getClusterName(), CassandraConnectorConf.ConnectionHostParam.option("127.0.0.1"))

  val df = spark.read
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(Map( "table" -> "tester", "keyspace" -> "test"))
    .load()

  df.show()


#sbt dependency
libraryDependencies += "org.testcontainers" % "cassandra" % "1.15.3" % Test
```

Output showing Actual port

```
Testing started at 5:30 PM ...
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53611', transport: 'socket'
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/kenneth/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.16/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/kenneth/.cache/coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.7.30/slf4j-nop-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the local port in your code:

```scala
val port = container.getMappedPort(9042)
```

TestContainers provide `getMappedPort` specifically for this purpose: it will give you the local port mapped to the port specified as parameter in the container (the local port mapped to 9042 in Cassandra container in your case).

Note: you must start the container before calling `getMappedPort` but that is already your case.

Comment: I keep getting the error below

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {localhost:9042} :: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=72a5db29): [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request (java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException)] 

```

Comment: 9042 is the port when you are inside the container, you should use `port` given by `getMappedPort` outside of the container.

Comment: Hi I have tried both 9042 and output of port, both dont seem to work and anytime I run the test I see the output

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53611', transport: 'socket', with a different port each time.

Comment: The "connected to the target VM" has nothing to do with testcontainers, just ignore it.